# Sending mail from Java: works in Eclipse but fails when deployed?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, eclipse-luna

I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException` when trying to deploy my mail-sending application to a production environment.

It works fine in the IDE (Eclipse Luna).

All jars found in the project path are present in the production environment.

There appears to be some magic dependency which is not shown as a Referenced Library in the project.

What's the quickest fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` and a `ClassNotFoundException` typically indicate that your classpath is missing relevant classes, `javax.mail.MessagingException` in this case

The class `javax.mail.MessagingException` is part of the Java EE library. You can download it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) (download the JAR if you are not using Maven). Add the library to your runtime classpath. Perhaps it was managed differently by your IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded that jar and added to the production classpath, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @AlexR Please go into more detail. What did you do to add it to your classpath? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: I downloaded javaee-api-7.0.jar into my lib/ subdirectory. My command line starts with: java -classpath app.jar:lib/*.jar

Comment: # ls -l lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1930692 May 20  2013 lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar

Comment: @AlexR Is it possibly a shell expansion issue? Try `app.jar:lib/*`.

Comment: WHOAH. Removing the '.jar' fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're running a standalone program, not a Java EE application server, so you don't need or want the javaee-api jar file.  You do need the complete JavaMail runtime jar file however.  If you don't already have it, you'll find a pointer on the [JavaMail java.net project page](http://javamail.java.net).